# ASP.Net Core second submit button brings back old model data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am building a search page with 3 sections a user can post back from.

1) A Search Criteria form with search fields and a Search Button tag helper of type submit. It has this attribute: asp-route-newSearch="true"

```
<button asp-route-newSearch="true" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    Search
</button>
```

2) A Quick Search area with anchor tag helpers and an asp-route-QuickSearchType attributes. Values of the quick search can be statuses like "Completed", "Resolved" and so on.

Links here look like:

```
<a asp-controller="InternalAudit" asp-action="Index" asp-route-QuickSearchType="Unresolved" class="quick-search-link">
    <i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>View Unresolved Audits
</a>
```

3)  A pager section where the user selects a Page number and click GO.
Go is also a tag helper button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    GO
</button>
```

The outer form looks like this:

```
<form asp-controller="InternalAudit" asp-action="Index" class="form-horizontal">
```

Here is the flow of my bug:

When I first go to the page it looks like this:

[image]

Now I search and the screen looks like this:

[image]

I've written out PageNum from the Model. It says one and the Pager Dropdown is 1.
Now if I change the Pager drop down to 3 and click GO it looks correct. GO as a second Submit Button works here.

[image]

Now if I change the Search Criteria and click Search, you can see where I write out the Model var PageNum it is correctly 1.
But the dropdown is still on page 3.

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Here is my controller and action signiture:

```
public class InternalAuditController : Controller
    {
        private IOfficeRepository _OfficeRepo;
        private IInternalAuditRepository _internalAuditRepo;
        public InternalAuditController(IInternalAuditRepository internalAuditRepo, IOfficeRepository officeRepo)
        {
            _internalAuditRepo = internalAuditRepo;
            _OfficeRepo = officeRepo;
        }

        public ViewResult Index(InternalAuditListVM internalAuditListVM, bool newSearch)
        {
```

In the next section I reset the paging info to PageNum 1 if this is a new search or the first time hitting the page.
And make Quick Search null if this is a new search:

```
var internalAudits = _internalAuditRepo.InternalAudits;
// First hit or new search: need to initialize PageNum to 1;
if (internalAuditListVM.PagingInfo == null || newSearch == true)
{
    internalAuditListVM.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo();
}
if (newSearch == true)
{
    internalAuditListVM.QuickSearchType = null;
}
```

Here is the quick search section:

```
            #region QuickSearching
            if (internalAuditListVM.QuickSearchType != null)
            {
                internalAuditListVM.InternalAuditSearchCriteria = null;
                internalAudits = internalAudits.Where(ia => ia.Status == internalAuditListVM.QuickSearchType);
            }
            #endregion
```

Then several filtering sections that look like this:

```
string auditAcnSearchText = internalAuditListVM.InternalAuditSearchCriteria?.AuditAcnCd;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(auditAcnSearchText))
            {
                internalAudits = internalAudits.Where(ia => ia.AuditAcnCd.Contains(auditAcnSearchText));
            }
```

Then I prepare the dropdowns:

```
#region Prepare SelectLists for Drop Downs
            IQueryable<SelectListItem> offices = _OfficeRepo.Offices.OrderBy(o => o.OfficeOrganizationCd)
                .Where(o => o.OfficeActiveCd == "Y")
                .Select(o => new SelectListItem
                { Text = o.OfficeOrganizationCd, Value = o.OfficeID.ToString() });

            IQueryable<SelectListItem> issuers = _internalAuditRepo.InternalAudits
                .OrderBy(i => i.Issuer)
                .Select(a => new SelectListItem { Text = a.Issuer }).Distinct();
            #endregion
```

Prepare the VM and return like this;

```
internalAuditListVM.InternalAudits = internalAudits;
            internalAuditListVM.OfficeList = offices.ToList();
            internalAuditListVM.IssuerList = issuers.ToList();

            return 

return View(internalAuditListVM);
```

Does anybody know why the Select tag helper is not binding when I click "Search"?

I have static  tags in there right now because I am still working on the paging.

---

There is a second part to my question.

From where I left off in my bug flow, if I now click the "Unresolved" quick search link I get this screen.

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

PageNum is 1 and Quicksearch is "Unresolved" both in my debug Model writeout area and in the Search Results.
Now if I select page 2 from the drop down and click GO I get this screen:

[image]

Page 2 of unresolved.  Everything is correct.

Now I start a new search:

And I get this screen:

[image]

So the debug writeout says Page 1 and QuickSearch: NULL which is correct.
But the screen has page 2 selected in the drop down.
Finally here is the worst part of the bug.
Now if I click GO it goes back to Unresolved.  How did my QuickSearch get set back to that old value in the model from two clicks ago?:

[image]

Here are my ViewModels for reference

```
public class InternalAuditListVM
    {
        public InternalAuditSearchCriteria InternalAuditSearchCriteria { get; set; }
        public string QuickSearchType { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<InternalAudit> InternalAudits { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> OfficeList;
        public List<SelectListItem> IssuerList;

    }

public class InternalAuditSearchCriteria
    {
        [Display(Name = "Audit Control Number:")]
        public string AuditAcnCd { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int OfficeId { get; set; }
        public string Issuer { get; set; }
    }

public class PagingInfo
    {
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; } = 4;
        public int PageNum { get; set; } = 1;

        public int TotalPages =>
            (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / PageSize);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this long post.  But it always seems to help when I write it out.

This is the modifcation I made in my  beginning setup of the controller:

```
var internalAudits = _internalAuditRepo.InternalAudits;
        // First hit or new search: need to initialize PageNum to 1;
        if (internalAuditListVM.PagingInfo == null || newSearch == true)
        {
            ModelState.Remove("PagingInfo.PageNum");
            internalAuditListVM.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo();
        }
        if (newSearch == true)
        {
            ModelState.Remove("QuickSearchType");
            internalAuditListVM.QuickSearchType = null;
        }
```

I added these two lines:

```
ModelState.Remove("PagingInfo.PageNum");
```

and

```
ModelState.Remove("QuickSearchType");
```

There are a few threads out here on stack that talk about this but I just couldn't get it to work until I had fooled around with it for hours.
At least I have a little idea now and a little experience dealing with this error when it crops up.